# Online backup of Cloud servers?

Tags: linux, windows, sql-server, backup

We have several servers "in the cloud".  These run web sites, sql server, postgres, etc...

The cloud service we're using (rackspacecloud) only allows backups up to 2GB, and our sql server and other instances are larger than that.  We also have servers running at Amazon.  We want to have a centralized backup of all our data that is agnostic as to which cloud service we're using.

So.. I'm looking for backup solutions that work across both Windows and Linux, can backup SQL and Postgres, and potentially handle local backups as well (backups of our in-office desktops and servers) which would include Small Business Server with exchange and local SQL Server instances.

I'm not looking for anything that's overly complicated to setup, and it must be secure (encryption of links as well as data on the remote servers in a manner that doesn't allow their employees to access the data).

Continuous backup would also be nice, but not truly necessary.

Does anyone have any suggestions for potential online backup services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the database portions you'll need to configure the native database backup processes to dump to disk, and allow what ever product you use for remote backup to pickup those files and upload them.  For SQL Server for example, you'll want to setup nightly full backups (as an example) will transaction log backups through out the day.  Then the backup software (Mozy business for example) can grab the backups with the SQL Server has generated and upload them from the server to Mozy.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this method.  I'm just looking for a more integrated backup solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you click in the right places, the Rackspace Cloud Control Panel will let you create backups for slices over 2GB. There is a pretty simple tutorial [here](http://failverse.com/creating-backups-for-cloud-servers-larger-than-2gb/).

There is a caveat though:

> The total size of the sparce disk file that your virtual hard disk resides upon cannot be larger than 160GB.  What this means is that the highest amount of disk space in use at one time in your server’s history cannot have exceeded 160GB.  If you were using more disk space than that in the past, you are basically SOL;  the only way to make a backup image is to copy your data to a new server (assuming you have <160GB in use currently) and then take a snapshot of that new machine.

And (though unrelated) Linux servers cannot be backed up if they occupy more than 75GB of disk space, or 3 million inodes.

Comment: I've never seen such a helpful unhelpful answer.  Lol.  "If you click in the right place"???  I have clicked everywhere, and I can find no hidden way to do backups.

Comment: A link to the blog you quoted might have been halpful.  I found it here http://failverse.com/creating-backups-for-cloud-servers-larger-than-2gb/  Unfortunately, I don't think this is valid anymore as Rackspace has recently changed their "with server" backup policy and now stores all images as cloud files.

Comment: I did include a link. Reading is fundamental, sir. And this method applies to both Cloud Files and With-Server backups. Additionally, if you wish to have snapshot images be taken With-Server, you'll need to contact support.